# A unitary operator is a closed operator

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $\mathcal{H}$ be an infinite-dimensional Hilbert space, with $U$ a densely defined, unitary operator. I was wondering if such an operator is in fact a closed operator, which is equivalent to
\begin{equation}
U=U^{**}\,,\quad (1)
\end{equation}
where $^*$ denotes the adjoint. I am following the book *Distributions and Operators* by Gerd Grubb, Section 12. In this book, for a densely defined operator $T:\mathcal{H}\rightarrow \mathcal{H}$, the adjoint $T^*$ is said to be a closed operator. I then use Theorem 12.7, which says the following for an operator $T$. Assume $T$ is; 1: Densely defined. 2: Closed. 3: Injective. 4: Has range dense in $\mathcal{H}$.

If these properties hold for $T$, then $T^*$ and $T^{-1}$ has the same properties.

Now, in the above Theorem, if I instead of $T$ consider the operator $U^*$, then it is closed as argued. Furthermore, because $U$ is a unitary ($U^*U = UU^*=1)$, then that must imply $U^*$ is both densely defined, injective and has dense range in $\mathcal{H}$, no? From this, I conclude that $(U^*)^{-1}=U$ has the same properties, that is, $U$ is in particular closed.

Is there something I am completely missing here? I know I am working with densely defined operators, so $(1)$ does not hold for any arbitrary linear operator, but in this case it is my understanding that it does hold true.

Is this true?

Comment: A unitary operator can be extended to a continuous operator on the whole Hilbert space and all continuous operators defined on the whole Hilbert space are closed (by the closed graph theorem).

Comment: Also for any bounded operator $A$ (defined on the whole Hilbert space) we have $A^{**}=A$. The only possible difference between $A$ and $A^{**}$ would be its domain. However, for bounded operators it is just the whole Hilbert space.

Comment: So your reasoning is correct, though a bit like nuking a fly ;-)

Comment: Of course! Yes I see the proof in another book, follows quite simply. Thank you so much.

Comment: You are welcome. And welcome to this site :)

Comment: @Severin what is the definition of a closed operator you are referring to when you say by the closed graph theorem every bounded operator is closed ?

Comment: @NotaChoice I use the definition that we call an operator closed iff its graph is closed.

Comment: so what are closed operators that are not bounded?